# Two Digit Month & Day

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Below is a code I use to digitally sign and date in acrobat. The formatting of the date I need is `YYYYMMDD` (ie: `20180808`) but the code I have doesn't show the two digit month or day. I've done research for getting the two digit month/date but all answers I've found don't work with the code I have, well I can't get it to work. Any help would be great.

```
// JavaScript code to add the date at signing time
    var currentTime = new Date()

    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1

    var day = currentTime.getDate()

    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

    var signingTime = year +"/"+month+"/"+day



    var f = this.getField("undefined");  



    f.value = signingTime;


var fieldsToLock = ["undefined"];
for (var i in fieldsToLock) this.getField(fieldsToLock[i]).readonly = true;
```

Comment: It's great that you did research, but could you elaborate on it a bit? Ideally we want to know what your research found. It saves time, since we won't find the same things you did

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a `0` later by your self like follows:

```
var currentTime = new Date(),
    month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1,
    day = currentTime.getDate(),
    year = currentTime.getFullYear();

day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
month = month < 10 ? '0' + day : day;

var signingTime = year +"/"+month+"/"+day;

var f = this.getField("undefined");  

f.value = signingTime;

var fieldsToLock = ["undefined"];
for (var i in fieldsToLock)
    this.getField(fieldsToLock[i]).readonly = true;
```